# ion-tab detect a second select

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I'm having a problem regarding ionic2 with ion-tabs.

When I tap an ion-tab the first time, the constructor for that page (SettingsPage for example) gets called. When I navigate away and tap the same ion-tab again, the constructor doesn't get called (kind of makes sense).

Is there any way for me to call the constructor again? If not the constructor, at least a predefined function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's happening because the page used as tab is being created only the first time you're selecting that tab. After that, since the tab already exists, it won't be created again (and thus, the constructor is not going to be called).

If you want to execute some code every time a tab gets selected, use `ionViewDidEnter` instead:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-a-tab',
  templateUrl: 'app/a-tab.page.html'
})
export class ATabPage {

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {}

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    // This code will be executed every time the tab is selected! :)
  }

}
```